# How to fix [industries_mfg_common:mfgAnalyticsDashboard] attribute [dashboardName]: Error while fetching dashboards?

Tags: managed-package, package-install, summer-23

Have you encountered the following error message while attempting to install a managed package?

```
Error (1): Encountered errors installing the package! Installation errors: 
1) (CustomRecordPage) Component [industries_mfg_common:mfgAnalyticsDashboard] attribute [dashboardName]: Error while fetching dashboards, Details: CustomRecordPage: Component [industries_mfg_common:mfgAnalyticsDashboard] attribute [dashboardName]: Error while fetching dashboards
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the Salesforce R&D team is working to resolve this bug, but in the meantime, you can follow this workaround to fix it without impacting production, as it is not currently on the Summer '23 release.
Enabling the CRM Analytics and checking one option should fix the issue, please follow these steps:

1. Switch to Classic mode.
2. Go to Setup.
3. Search for "Getting Started" under Analytics.
4. Click on the green button labeled "Enable CRM Analytics."
5. In the Quick Find box, enter "Settings" and select it under Analytics.
6. Choose "Open Salesforce records in new browser tabs."
7. Save it

Now you should be able to install your managed package.

Answer (score 0):

There is the following known issues you can track - with the fix in Summer '23.

[Salesforce Manufacturing Analytics Dashboard (MFG) errors](https://issues.salesforce.com/issue/a028c00000tIpW2/salesforce-manufacturing-analytics-dashboard-mfg-errors)

With the workaround listed as

1. Assign the "Manufacturing Analytics Admin" permission set and "CRM Analytics Plus Admin" permission set to the admin
2. Go to Setup -> Analytics -> Getting started and Enable CRM Analytics
3. Attempt your action again